# Missing value in the Attribute value list

Tags: gooddata

I’m creating a metric with a condition that is looking for a value in the attribute value list, but that value doesn't exist in the Attribute values appearance.
Here is my case:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(Fctpropertyunitsummarykey) WHERE Propertystate = Active
AND Stage Name IN (Construction,Inspection,Leased,Trustee Occ/Eviction, 'Vacant')
```

‘Vacant’ value doesn’t appear at this time.

What is the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it does not exist there, it means the value is currently not in the workspace. The easiest way is to upload the attribute value. If not possible you could adjust your metric and try to use the [LIKE/ILIKE Clause](https://help.gooddata.com/doc/enterprise/en/dashboards-and-insights/maql-analytical-query-language/maql-expression-reference/filter-expressions/filtering-with-the-like-clause). The condition should look somehow as in my example below:

```
...WHERE Stage name ILIKE "%Vacant%"
```

Just make sure that you are working with the Attribute label and not with the Attribute itself.

If you build metric in a master workspace for LCM, the data, including also the missing "Vacant" value, should be loaded into the Master workspace. Just be aware, if the value doesn't exist in the Client workspace, such metric wouldn't be computable.